# Why is more than one element not inserting in a set of structures?

Tags: c++, set, structure

I want to insert multiple structure objects into a set but one one element gets inserted to the set. What am I doing wrong?

```
struct Productions {
    char LHS;
    string RHS;
    bool operator<(const Productions& t) const { 
        return (this->LHS < t.LHS); 
    } 
};

int main() {

    int NoP;
    cout<<"Enter No. of Productions: ";
    cin>>NoP;
    set<Productions> old_prod;
    Productions prod;
    for(int i=0; i<NoP; i++) {
        cout<<"Enter Production No. "<<i+1<<":"<<endl;
        cout<<"LHS: ";
        cin>>prod.LHS;
        cout<<"RHS: ";
        cin>>prod.RHS;
        old_prod.insert(prod);
    }

    cout<<old_prod.size()<<endl;
    for(auto it=old_prod.begin(); it!=old_prod.end(); it++) {
        cout<<it->LHS<<"->"<<it->RHS<<endl;
    }
}
```

The output is like this:
[terminal snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiNQ8.png).

I have also tried:

```
int main() {

    int NoP;
    cout<<"Enter No. of Productions: ";
    cin>>NoP;
    set<Productions> old_prod;
    for(int i=0; i<NoP; i++) {
        cout<<"Enter Production No. "<<i+1<<":"<<endl;
        Productions *prod = new Productions; 
        cout<<"LHS: ";
        cin>>prod->LHS;
        cout<<"RHS: ";
        cin>>prod->RHS;
        old_prod.insert(*prod);
    }

    cout<<old_prod.size()<<endl;
    for(auto it=old_prod.begin(); it!=old_prod.end(); it++) {
        cout<<it->LHS<<"->"<<it->RHS<<endl;
    }
}
```

But the output remains same. What am I missing?

Comment: @Sasanka Sekhar I can not reproduce the wrong behavior of the first program.

Comment: please include the input also in the question as text.

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. If you're asking why set doesn't permit duplicates then your [mcve] would be simply some headers and a `main`, with `std::set<int> s; s.insert(1); s.insert(1); for (const auto el : s) std::cout << el << '\n';` in it. Please edit your question to contain a [mcve] or risk it being closed. Also simply _read the documentation_ for the language features that you use, particularly when their behaviour surprises you.

Comment: That's kind of how [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (and sets in general) works. Are you sure you want a set and not e.g. a [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inputting the same value for the data member `char LHS;`. And the elements are ordered in the set according to this data member

```
bool operator<(const Productions& t) const { 
    return (this->LHS < t.LHS); 
}
```

So all other inputs are ignored except the first input to the set.

Use different values for the data member `LHS`.

Or redefine the comparison operator the following way

```
bool operator<(const Productions& t) const { 
    return this->LHS < t.LHS && this->RHS < t.RHS; 
}
```

or if to use tuples then write

```
bool operator<(const Productions& t) const { 
    return std::tie( this->LHS, this->RHS ) < std::tie( t.LHS, t.RHS ); 
}
```

In this case you have to include the header `<tuple>`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct Productions {
    char LHS;
    string RHS;
    bool operator<(const Productions& t) const { 
        return std::tie( this->LHS, this->RHS ) < std::tie( t.LHS, t.RHS ); 
    } 
};

int main() {

    int NoP;
    cout<<"Enter No. of Productions: ";
    cin>>NoP;
    set<Productions> old_prod;
    Productions prod;
    for(int i=0; i<NoP; i++) {
        cout<<"Enter Production No. "<<i+1<<":"<<endl;
        cout<<"LHS: ";
        cin>>prod.LHS;
        cout<<"RHS: ";
        cin>>prod.RHS;
        old_prod.insert(prod);
    }

    cout<<old_prod.size()<<endl;
    for(auto it=old_prod.begin(); it!=old_prod.end(); it++) {
        cout<<it->LHS<<"->"<<it->RHS<<endl;
    }
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter No. of Productions: 3
Enter Production No. 1:
LHS: S
RHS: aSa
Enter Production No. 2:
LHS: S
RHS: bSb
Enter Production No. 3:
LHS: S
RHS: c
3
S->aSa
S->bSb
S->c
```

Another approach is to use `std::multiset` instead of `std::set` if you want to have duplicated values of the key.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct Productions {
    char LHS;
    string RHS;
    bool operator<(const Productions& t) const { 
        return (this->LHS < t.LHS); 
    } 
};

int main() {

    int NoP;
    cout<<"Enter No. of Productions: ";
    cin>>NoP;
    multiset<Productions> old_prod;
    Productions prod;
    for(int i=0; i<NoP; i++) {
        cout<<"Enter Production No. "<<i+1<<":"<<endl;
        cout<<"LHS: ";
        cin>>prod.LHS;
        cout<<"RHS: ";
        cin>>prod.RHS;
        old_prod.insert(prod);
    }

    cout<<old_prod.size()<<endl;
    for(auto it=old_prod.begin(); it!=old_prod.end(); it++) {
        cout<<it->LHS<<"->"<<it->RHS<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I didn't know the other inputs were getting ignored.

Comment: @SasankaSekhar You could use std::multiset if you want to have duplicated values.

Answer (score 3):

If the elements you insert have same `LHS` they are considered equivalent as per your operator<, and a set stores only one instance of equivalent ones.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set):

> `std::set` is an associative container that contains a sorted set of **unique** objects of type Key.

Uniqueness is assured by simply not inserting an element if there is already an equivalent element in the set. See the documentation on [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert):

> Inserts element(s) into the container, if the container doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key.

Two elements, `a` and `b` are considere equivalent if neither `a<b` nor `b<a` evaluates to true. Note that equivalence does not necessarily imply equality, ie `a == b`. As you compare only `LHS` in `operator<`, two entries with the same `LHS` are considered equivalent (see [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#3) for the relevant quote from the standard). You can have equivalent elements being equal, but then you need to compare also `RHS` in the operator.

It is not clear why you chose a set, because the above property is basically what makes a set a set. Maybe you want to use a `std::vector` instead. Alternatively you can fix your operator to also comapre `RHS`.

Comment: I suggest to emphasize that part about _equality check_, since this is likely what confuses OP. In his case, the keys are in fact **different by value**, but **equal from the perspective of `std::set`** due to a custom `operator<`. The relevant paragraph from the Standard is here: http://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#3.